# Can I kill people with a defibrillator?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is it possible to kill people with the defibrillator in Battlefield 3?

In Battlefield: Bad Company 2, it was an instant kill (I think).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can, but it's very hard. It requires at least two hits from full health, and only certain parts of the body will take damage (mainly the chest area).

Because of these two things, you'll only get kills on either really low health people, or people who are completely oblivious, and even then it'll require pretty good accuracy on your part.

Answer (score 7):

Just saw [this tweet](https://twitter.com/#!/Demize99/status/143708825009139712) coming from [a post on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/n53u6/why_cant_you_kill_with_the_defibrillator/).

Apparently if you hold down the trigger button while shocking someone it will kill them.

Haven't tested yet...

**UPDATE**

I tested this and it did work, but not the way I expected.  When holding down the button, the defib attack seems quite fast, but it still took 3 hits in order for me to kill someone.  I was aiming for the chest, but the player was prone, so I'm not sure if any of the attacks missed.

Comment: No idea why you got downvoted since you provided evidence as well as tested yourself, so have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have the evidence before... but I did have the reference.

Answer (score 2):

IF you can shock him right in the head I believe it is a one shot kill, but it is not as effective as it was in BF2 where a shock anywhere would kill him.Thus don't run around with your paddles out reviving continuosly anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you press forward while shocking it will kill in one shot.